# Production of hydroxide ions in reactions occuring in alkaline medium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Question similar to [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40869/124959) but with a more precise point. For this reaction in neutral or faintly alkaline medium: ([source](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/lech108.pdf) page 20) $$\ce{2MnO4- + H2O + I- -> 2MnO2 +2OH- +IO3-}$$
If the reaction is occuring in a basic medium,  new $\ce{OH-}$ ions are produced in the reaction, then by the Le Chatelier's principle the reaction will shift backwards and would be less favourable. Also, this is in contrast to reactions in acidic mediums involving consumption of $\ce{H+}$ ions present in bulk.
So,

> Why are $\ce{OH-}$ ions are being produced in this reaction?

Comment: $\ce{MnO2}$ as the product of $\ce{MnO4-}$ reduction is generaly formed in mildly acidic, neutral or mildly alkalic pH. Strongly alkalic pH prefers $\ce{MnO4^2-}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* an equilibrium reaction. It just goes to quantitative completion. In other words, the equilibrium constant of this reaction is exceedingly large. The reaction as shown below simply shows

$$\ce{2MnO4- + H2O + I- -> 2MnO2 +2OH- +IO3-}$$

that potassium permanganate can oxidize iodide ion in water as a solvent without pH adjustment. As a result, hydroxide ions are generated. If hydroxide ions were being consumed, they would be present on the left hand side. So this reaction has not been carried out in basic medium.

Comment: Since MnO2 is formed rather than reduction to Manganous ion it implies the reaction was run in neutral to basic conditions. H2O is still acidic in mild basic solutions.  The oxidation to Iodic acid is more facile in basic solution by almost one volt and the difference from iodate to periodate is about the same about -0.6v in both basic and acidic solutions. Perhaps the basic conditions help stop the reaction at iodate.

Comment: "H2O is still acidic in mild basic solutions." What does this mean?

Comment: It means that water is an acid in basic solutions. Peroxide reductions require a source of hydrogen ions, that source is water or hydrogen peroxide.